# How do i Download FTP root folder with its subfolder and files in C# using FTPwebRequest

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I want to download A ftp directory which has its sub directories and files, I am using C# Ftpwebrequst.

Comment: Is there any documentation? Have you read it?

Comment: I know how to download a file, but i do not have idea how to download a folder

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly download an entire folder in a single command. `FTP` does not support this. You would need to enumerate through all files in the directory and their subdirectories and download files one-by-one.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/079fb811-3c55-4959-85c4-677e4b20bea3/) is a thread from MSDN forums and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) is the documentation on `FtpWebRequest`-class from MSDN.

Comment: This Code is Working Fine, But its Skipping Empty Folders.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this and you will have to recurse into each folder inidividually:

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(FTPServerDirectory);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: This Code will Listing the Directory, I want to download Directory